# Receiving multiple images using multer in NodeJS problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, multer

I'm using multer package to receive multiple images from the frontend (ReactJS).I'm sending in additional to basic fields, an array of Images and I want to save them In my Rest API server using node.
I'm receiving my body fields but the problem is the images are not received. Here is my code:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(new Error('worng file format'), true);
    }
}

// initialize multer
const upload = multer(
    {
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter: fileFilter,
    } 
);

router.get('/', categoryController.getCategories);

router.post('/', upload.array('images', 3), (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        // here I want the images to save their location
        console.log(req.files);
        const name = req.body.name;
        const description = req.body.description;

    } catch (err) {
        
    }
});
```

Here is how I'm sending the images array:
[image]

The folder `upload` where my images should be, is empty;
So, how do I save my multiple images ?

Comment: I can't spot anything strange. What does `console.log(req.files)` print?

Comment: @MaximOrlov it prints an empty array. "[ ]" like this

Comment: Are the files perhaps rejected by the filefilter function? If you console.log `file` at the top of the function, before anything else, what do you get?

Comment: fileFilter function not working for me for some reason. I tried to put a console.log and debug but the function didn't trigger perhaps @MaximOrlov

Comment: It seems the file is not coming through correctly to the backend. Think it might be something in the frontend. Can you try using `formData.append('image', selectedFiles[0]); formData.append('image', selectedFiles[1]); ...` instead and append each file separately.

Comment: Thank you man, this solved my problem

Comment: Glad to hear! I've added an answer for others facing the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append each file individually to the form:

```js
for (const file of selectedFiles) {
  formData.append('image', file);
}
```